# using variables from another class (different Pages) in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have an application consisting of different pages which are all placed inside a Frame (with status bar, menu bar etc.) and stacked on top of each other. By calling the function `lift`, I can bring the respective page on top of the others. (this is a minimum viable example, the complete program has around 2000 rows)

When I call `p1.lift` from my menu bar, Page 1 is brought up front - when I try the same from button on Page 2, it will tell me that `name p2 is not defined`. I get that, since I only referenced `Page2(self)` in my MainView class as `p2`.

If I change the button command to `command=Page2(self).lift`, the code runs, but the button is not doing anything. I also tried to pass a function with parameters via the `partial` module, but still no luck.

It will only work if I define a custom function, e.g. by name `LiftP2`, which does nothing more than what the class can do by itself - `p2.lift()`.

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why I need to use that workaround and how I could access it the same way asfrom the menu...since I did not write these classes (but generated them from other SO answers :)) and obviously miss some important concept here I would gladly take any assistance with the described problem.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()


class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        buttonToP1 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 2', command=LiftP2)
        buttonToP1.pack(fill=tk.X)


class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        buttonToP2 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 1', command=LiftP1, bg='yellow')
        buttonToP2.pack(fill=tk.X)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        global p1,p2
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)

        mainMenu = tk.Menu(self)
        root.config(menu=mainMenu)
        mainMenu.add_command(label='Navigate to Page 1', command=p1.lift)
        mainMenu.add_command(label='Navigate to Page 2', command=p2.lift)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p1.show()


def LiftP1():
    p1.lift()
def LiftP2():
    p2.lift()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)  
    root.title('Testapplication v01')
    root.wm_geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (300, 200, 100, 100))
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) and read [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Comment: i've come very far with my non-CS background, but whenever classes come into play, I somehow still don't get it. here e.g. I create the instance of class Page2 as p2, but I have no idea (despite all the googling...) how to access it from within another class.

Comment: Read the given link and focus to `Instance variable`

Comment: ***"miss some important concept here"***: After you have defined `p2` as `Instance variable` you can do `command=self.master.p2.lift`. `.master` is the default reference attribute in a `tkinter` object.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, since this issue can most likely only arise from a lack of basic OOP (?) knowledge, and I cannot see it being particularly useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `command=p2.lift` if `p2` doesn't exist - because it tries to find `lift` in `p2` to assign to `command=` and it can't find `p2`

So first you have to create instances (without `command=` in buttons) and later you have to assing `command=` in buttons.

```
    p1 = Page1(self)
    p2 = Page2(self)

    p1.buttonToP1['command'] = p2.lift
    p2.buttonToP2['command'] = p1.lift
```

(`command=p1.list` in `Page2` doesn't makes problem because `p1` already exists when it is executed but I use `['command']` for both buttons to make code identical)

It means also that you have to uses `self.` for `self.buttonToP1`, `self.buttonToP2`

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.buttonToP1 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 2')
        self.buttonToP1.pack(fill=tk.X)

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.buttonToP2 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 1', bg='yellow')
        self.buttonToP2.pack(fill=tk.X)

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #global p1,p2
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)

        p1.buttonToP1['command'] = p2.lift
        p2.buttonToP2['command'] = p1.lift

        mainMenu = tk.Menu(self)
        root.config(menu=mainMenu)
        mainMenu.add_command(label='Navigate to Page 1', command=p1.lift)
        mainMenu.add_command(label='Navigate to Page 2', command=p2.lift)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)  
    root.title('Testapplication v01')
    root.wm_geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (300, 200, 100, 100))
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Other method is to uses your functions as methods in class. And then you assign existing method `command=self.change` so it makes no problem

```
class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        buttonToP1 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 2', command=self.change)
        buttonToP1.pack(fill=tk.X)

    def change(self):
        p2.lift()

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        buttonToP2 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 1', command=self.change, bg='yellow')
        buttonToP2.pack(fill=tk.X)

    def change(self):
        p2.lift()
```

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        buttonToP1 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 2', command=self.change)
        buttonToP1.pack(fill=tk.X)

    def change(self):
        p2.lift()

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        buttonToP2 = tk.Button(self, text='Go to Page 1', command=self.change, bg='yellow')
        buttonToP2.pack(fill=tk.X)

    def change(self):
        p2.lift()

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        global p1, p2

        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)

        mainMenu = tk.Menu(self)
        root.config(menu=mainMenu)
        mainMenu.add_command(label='Navigate to Page 1', command=p1.lift)
        mainMenu.add_command(label='Navigate to Page 2', command=p2.lift)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)  
    root.title('Testapplication v01')
    root.wm_geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (300, 200, 100, 100))
    root.mainloop()
```